# Is it possible to prevent user from sending text messages or use a specific application from the android code?

Tags: android, service, message

I would like to know if there is a way to create a service in the application which would prevent user from texting or using specific apps.

Comment: you're not allowed to mess with other apps beyond http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : NO.

You can be able to see what they send and receive, you need a permission for that though, but you can't prevent them from sending a text message.